# If $A$ is normal then $A^*=P(A)$ for some polynomial $P$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Since $A$ is normal it has a diagonal matrix with respect to some orthonormal basis, and the same is true of $A^*$ using the same unitary matrix. We also know that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\bar\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*$. Using interpolating polynomials, make a polynomial that sends $\lambda_i$ to $\bar\lambda_i$. Is this the polynomial we want? So far we haven't used normality. I'm wondering if that comes into the works when we might say how $P(QAQ^H)=QP(A)Q^H$ or something.

Comment: Don't you use normality when you say that $A^\ast$ is diagonalized by **the same** orthonormal basis as $A$?

Comment: Even more, you already use normality (and you even say so yourself) when you say that $A$ is diagonal with respect to some orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

By normality, we have that $A = U\Lambda U^*$, where $U$ is unitary. Note the following.
\begin{align}
p(A) &= p(U\Lambda U^*) \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k \left(U\Lambda U^* \right)^k \\
&= U\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k \Lambda^k \right) U^* \\
&= Up(\Lambda)U^* \\ \\
A^* &= U\Lambda^*U^*\\
\end{align}
Which in turn implies that 
\begin{align}
p(A) = A^* &\Leftrightarrow Up(\Lambda)U^* = U\Lambda^*U^* \\
&\Leftrightarrow p(\Lambda) = \Lambda^*\\
&\Leftrightarrow p(\lambda_k) = \lambda^*_k \, (\forall k).
\end{align}